# Attribute Change Script

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, script

I have created a custom attribute in magento (code 'discount_int'). Now I wish to update this attribute across all my products (all 17000) of them. I need this value to reflect the percentage discount difference. Now from reading I believe I can do this via a script. Having gone backwards and forwards from various points of information. I have created a .php script (as seen below) now as far as my knowledge goes I thought that I could just run it from a browser and update the attributes. I must be going wrong somewhere. Can someone shed some light on why this isnt working?

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/../app/Mage.php';

umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$count = 0;
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$updateParents = array();

$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addTaxPercents();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()){
        $diffAmt = $product->getPrice() - $product->getFinalPrice();
        $discountPer = ($diffAmt/ $product->getPrice()) * 100;
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
             array($product->getId()), //products to update
             array('discount_int' => $discountPer), //attributes to update
             0 //store to update. 0 means global values
        );
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically I found if you add line

```
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

You will not able to get the product id because of the functions `addMinimalPrice(), addFinalPrice(), addTaxPercents();`

You will need to remove those three function from collection and try again, it should work.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, deleted those lines and it looks like it has tried to run, however got the error 
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 85 bytes) in /var/www/v                                       hosts/blueridge.co.uk/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 290
Is there a way of maybe getting it to do it in steps rather than trying to do all at once? So would I be able to maybe specify certain attribute sets for it to do one at a time? (as 17000 products seems like I will run into this issue no matter how big I increase the memory limit....

Comment: your server not able to update all product attribute due to large set of products. you will need to increase memory limit of your server or you can do it in the part of products.

Comment: It has been running this all day, for the fact I believe it is possibly stuck in a loop or just not updating anything. Is there a way of checking status on it while its running?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/../app/Mage.php';

umask(0);
$count = 0;
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$updateParents = array();

$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('discount_int')
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addTaxPercents();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()){
        $diffAmt = $product->getPrice() - $product->getFinalPrice();
        $discountPer = ($diffAmt/ $product->getPrice()) * 100;
        $product->setDiscountInt($discountPer);
        $product->setId($product->getId());
        $product->save();
    }
}

?>
```

**OR Second way**

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('admin');
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()){
        $diffAmt = $product->getPrice() - $product->getFinalPrice();
        $discountPer = ($diffAmt/ $product->getPrice()) * 100;
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()),array('discount_int' => $discountPer),$product->getStoreId());
    }
}

?>
```